# P/Invoke EntryPointNotFoundException when trying to allocate pointer containers

Tags: c#, mono, pinvoke, dllimport

I try to call a DllImport on the following Alsa function (from the [documentation](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/group___seq_client.html#g57321b9b7cd869801af9b18c25209eb5):

> ```
> #define snd_seq_client_info_alloca( ptr )  __snd_alloca(ptr, snd_seq_client_info)
> ```
>
> allocate a snd_seq_client_info_t
>   container on stack

Here is an implementation  that I have found in C++ while reading the code of an [application](http://drobilla.net/blog/software/patchage/) similar to what I want to accomplish in Mono:

```
snd_seq_client_info_t* cinfo;
snd_seq_client_info_alloca(&cinfo);
```

And here is what I have so far, but it is not working:

```
[DllImport(libasound.so.2)]
private static extern void snd_seq_client_info_alloca(out IntPtr ptr);

internal static void MyFunction ()
{
    IntPtr clientInfo = IntPtr.Zero;
    snd_seq_client_info_alloca(out clientInfo);
    // and then some more ...
}
```

But I get the following exception:

```
System.EntryPointNotFoundException: snd_seq_client_info_alloca
at (wrapper managed-to-native)   
MonoMultiJack.ConnectionWrapper.Alsa.LibAsoundWrapper:snd_seq_client_info_alloca (intptr&)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`snd_seq_client_info_alloca` is a pre-processor macro. You cannot P/Invoke pre-processor macros, only properly exported functions.

`snd_seq_client_info_alloca` expands to `__snd_alloca` which is a preprocessor macro as well.

`__snd_alloca` essentially expands to a call to [`alloca`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/alloca.3.html). You could try to rewrite this in C#. But I believe it doesn't make a lot of sense to allocate memory in the stack frame of the caller if the caller is managed code.

Just allocate some memory somewhere else (for example, using [Marshal.AllocHGlobal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s69bkh17.aspx)).

Comment: `EntryPointNotFoundException` and `#define`. D'oh, sometimes one just overlooks the obvious. Thanks. At least it compiles now, I just have to search the library code for the size of memory to allocate.

Comment: If you want to actually stackalloc from C# you can as well with teh stackalloc keyword, like so: int* block = stackalloc int[100];